# How to modify a regular expression for HTML tag name? and get that tags independent?

Tags: php, regex, text, syntax

The function prototype:

```
findHTMLElement( $output, $tagName );
```

Look at regular expression:

```
preg_match_all( "/\<{$tagName}(.*)\>(.*)\<(.*)\/(.*){$tagName}\>/is", $output, $matches );
```

If I have in the html this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="miarchivo.css">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="otroarchivo.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="otroarchivox.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="otroarchivox.js">xyzzz</script>
```

I will get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="miarchivo.css">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript"  src="otroarchivo.js">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript"  src="otroarchivox.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"  src="otroarchivox.js">xyzzz</script>
        ) )
```

And, what I want to get is:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="miarchivo.css">
        </script>

       [1] => <script type="text/javascript"  src="otroarchivo.js">
        </script>

        [2] => <script type="text/javascript"  src="otroarchivox.js"></script>

[3] =>        <script type="text/javascript"  src="otroarchivox.js">xyzzz</script>
            ) ) )
```

How to modify the Regular expression to get something like that!

Comment: What you want is to not use regex for HTML parsing. I'm fairly certain that there is a PHP library for that.

Comment: What's that library, I'm having some problems using DOMDocument ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [ungreedy modifier /U](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).